# Taking the mean of several data entries on same date to make one

Tags: regression, time-series, mean, dataset, loess

I am analyzing the number of likes of several influencers over time and I want to plot it to see if there is a trend.

Some influencers post several times on the same date, and then overall several influencers may post on the same date. Can I just take the mean for each date and plot those?

Or is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you should plot the number of posts/likes for each influencer for each date.

If you just take the overall mean on each date, the results won't relate back to which influencers were involved.

You could plot the means for each influencer per date, but they you lose the number of posts/likes behind the number.

Are you looking at influencer posts, influencer likes, or likes on influencer posts?

Comment: Thanks. I am not necessarily interested in which influencer were involved. I am looking at a general trend, the effect that hiding likes has on liking behavior. My data traces back a year, knowing that in November likes are hidden. I am trying to see if there is a 'dip' in likes in that month.

Comment: Can you see hidden likes, or do know that happened because they are gone?  I'm only familiar with likes on Facebook - you can unlike, but not hide likes.

Comment: So, I have scraped data from the back-end on Instagram. The made the change that users on the platform will only see 'SomeUserName and other have liked this'. But I still get the actual likecount per post with scraping (e.g. 5324 likes). I am trying to see if users are less likely to like a post when they are not presented with a numerical value.

Comment: What numerical value?